# How to choose pch symbols for a factor in R?

Tags: r, symbols, pch

I have tried to find out how to choose the symbols used for the factorial parameter in a case like this:

```
plot(data.3$age,data.3$tl,pch=c(data.3$mu),col=c(data.3$mu),
cex=1.5,cex.lab=1.3,cex.axis=1.5,las=1,bty="n",xlab="Age (years)",
ylab="Male Total Length (mm)",ylim=c(0,780),xlim=c(0,20))
```

I have used `pch=as.numeric(factor)` but I want to be able to choose the symbols myself because I find the default ones quite difficult to distinguish from each other.

I guess it's fairly simple but I have really tried to find out how to do this.

Comment: You don't need to wrap your parameters in `c()`.

Comment: You can pass in the `character`s to pch to specify exactly what you want to use, including unicode characters, eg `plot(1:2,1:2,pch=c("\u2191","\u2193"))`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Well, I tried this before, and although it works when you have two parameters, adding the third give only error messages.

Answer (score 4):

You can see the values available for `pch` in this plot.  (Make the figure window wide for best viewing.)

```
i <- -128:25
plot(i, pch = i, bg = "blue")
```

Negative numbers are [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/).

---

I think that this is what you are asking for, but I don't know why you are drawing a plot like this.  A set of histograms or boxplots would make more sense.

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  x = 1:20, 
  y = factor(sample(letters[1:4], 20, replace = TRUE))
)
pch_lookup <- c(a = 3, b = 10, c = 15, d = 20)
with(dummy, plot(x, y, pch = pch_lookup[as.character(y)]))
```

Comment: I don't get this one. I might have been a bit unclear in my question.  I have no problem adding any symbol to a normal regression. However, when I want to add an additional factor with, let say two levels, I cannot find a soloution for chosing symbols for these two levels?

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to know what each `pch` value looked like so you could choose values for each level.

Comment: Ah, no, sorry. I want to be able to choose the pch of the factor levels in an Ancova. I'm obviously useless speaking the statistic-language.

Answer (score 3):

A graphical representation of the `pch` symbols and the associated values can be found on many pages, e.g., [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two answers, the choice of which depends on how your factor levels are set up:

**First**, if your factor levels start at 1, and are sequential after that (so factors levels are 1,2,3,4 in the example below):

```
plot(data.3$age,data.3$tl, pch = c(21,10,22,7)[as.numeric(pch=c(data.3$mu))] )
```

**Second**, if your factor levels are not sequential (say you have subsetted a larger data set, with 7 factors, but you are only interested in plotting 4 of them):

```
plot(data.3$age,data.3$tl, pch = c(21,10,22,7)[as.numeric(as.factor(as.character(pch=c(data.3$mu))))] )
```

Comment: The syntax in the first suggestion here didn't work for me. This post was better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919816/plotting-in-different-shapes-using-pch-argument